# Why filter chain is never called?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm currently working on a web app which is accessible from a pool of applications. Basically, this pool provides a set of links to each app passing a key identifying the previously logged in user.

The application in question should authorize the user with the given token (possibly from any request url), store the user into spring security context and process the controller. It happens that spring security filters are not called and the controller is returning to `500` instead of `403`.

I tried some stuffs and ended up with a custom entry point forwarding to the custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to retrive the user and then the custom `AuthenticationProvider` should authorize the retrived user, but I'm pretty sure it's not the best way.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SwgenAuthFilter swgenAuthFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new SwgenEntryPoint())
            .and()
                .addFilter(swgenAuthFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(new SwgenAuthProvider()));
    }

}
```

**SwgenEntryPoint.java**

```
public class SwgenEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login");

        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

        return;
    }

}
```

**SwgenAuthFilter.java**

```
@Component
public class SwgenAuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityProvider securityProvider;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            User user = securityProvider.getUser(request, response);
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Eccezione scatenata durante l'autenticazione", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    static final private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @Secured({Role.ADMIN, Role.REGIONE})
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
    public String home(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // get user from SpringContextHolder
        User utente = Utils.getUser();

        if(utente != null) {
            logger.info("User correctly authenticated")
        }

        return "home";
    }
}
```

**STACKTRACE**

```
2016-12-01 12::03:07.343 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor] Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.lang.String it.regioneveneto.sanita.progettobase.controller.HomeController.home(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest); target is of class [it.regioneveneto.sanita.progettobase.controller.HomeController]; Attributes: [ROLE_MRA_ADMIN, ROLE_MRA_REGIONE, ROLE_MRA_ULSS]
dic 01, 2016 12:03:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/mra_auac] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext] with root cause
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:379)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at it.regioneveneto.sanita.progettobase.controller.HomeController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8c44d861.home(<generated>)
    ...
```

> Spring mvc: 4.3.4.RELEASE
>
> Spring security: 4.2.0.RELEASE

**EDIT:**

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>mra_auac</display-name>
    <description>MRA-AuAc</description>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>it.regioneveneto.sanita.progettobase.configuration.AppConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                it.regioneveneto.sanita.progettobase.configuration.HibernateConfig,
                it.regioneveneto.sanita.progettobase.configuration.security.SecurityConfig
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <multipart-config>
            <max-file-size>20971520</max-file-size><!--20MB -->
            <max-request-size>20971520</max-request-size><!--20MB -->
            <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.htm</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/500.htm</location>
    </error-page>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *shazin* pointed out your `web.xml` miss a reference to the `springSecurityFilterChain`. You can do it either his way as reported in the [Spring Documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/) using the xml format:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
  </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

**or** by including a class in your project that extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` like this:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer 
   extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {}
```

Then if you want to cut some code from your `web.xml` you can easily do that by **replacing**

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        it.regioneveneto.sanita.progettobase.configuration.HibernateConfig,
        it.regioneveneto.sanita.progettobase.configuration.security.SecurityConfig
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

annotating the class `AppConfig` with:

```
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class, HibernateConfig.class }) //remember to import them
```

Answer (score 1):

Your web.xml doesn't have the `springSecurityFilterChain` Filter specified.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingProxyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: This fixed the problem, but in another project, using Spring `4.2.5.RELEASE` and Spring Security `4.0.4.RELEASE` and the same configuration, I didn't need to add the `springSecurityFilterChain` in web.xml. What has changed?